# Estimating the False Reject Rate (FRR) of a classifier in production

Tags: classification, roc, false-discovery-rate

I have trained a binary classifier which runs in production on remote distributed devices (which are out of my control).

The model was trained on positive and negative samples, and I have chosen the thresholds of the model based on a standard [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic), reaching a desired False Reject Rate (FRR) and False Accept Rate (FAR).

I would like to **estimate** the FRR of the model in the true production environment.

The main problem is, that once in production the model only sends the Back-End samples which were **positively classified**.

Meaning - I can estimate the model's [False-Positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) and True-Positives in the production environment. 
However, I have no way of knowing its **False-Negatives**, therefore I cannot estimate the FRR under that setting.

I can, with many limitations, deploy alternative models with slightly lower thresholds in production, but I cannot (due to performance, and user experience) deploy models with much lower detection thresholds in the production environment.

I'm looking for an idea to estimate or bound the FRR in the production environment using the tools I have.